# With R markdown (or Quarto) can I reorder output sections?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am working on a scientific paper in R Markdown and it needs an abstract (with embedded results) at the start of the paper.  Currently the paper has analyses interspersed before the paragraphs and/or tables and figures where I report the results.  I can render the abstract at the end because all the parts have been calculated but I cant submit the paper like this.  I hate to front load all the analysis code (out of context) so I have the numbers ready for the abstract.

Does anybody have a strategy for this?

I know I can manually cut and paste the abstract to the top after rendering the document but that wrecks an otherwise fully reproducible workflow.

The best idea I have come up with (but I have not tried yet) is to save the .md file that is generated as the Rmd is processed and then programmatically parse the file and feed the abstract then the body of the paper directly to pandoc.

Is there a good solution to this using Quarto?

Comment: Maybe this [extension](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/abstract-section) helps!

Answer (score 0):

Both rmarkdown (through [`{bookdown}`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html)) and [`{quarto}`](https://quarto.org/docs/books/) will allow you to assemble a series of rmd/qmd files into a single document and use a YAML file to specify the order in which they should be assembled.

I'm currently using something like this for developing a standard reporting format for some research on human/machine interfaces. Intended for an applied scientist/engineer audience, which is not so different from your academic journal application.

Comment: Thank you @M-Wood. I have played with those options but as far as I can tell they require me to run the code twice (with a parametrized report keeping different sections of output).   The analysis for the paper is intense.  So that is a lot of time. Have you found a way to avoid running the code more than once while keeping different sections in each run?

Comment: If you use the clicky-menu in RStudio to render, you are correct.

If you are comfortable running a command from the root directory of the project in command line or powershell, you can use `quarto render` to produce the report in all the formats specified in the YAML. More info here: https://quarto.org/docs/projects/quarto-projects.html#rendering-projects